# Thymeleaf: could not parse as expression for links

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to thymeleaf, and don't understand this error.

> 2020-04-16 16:20:24.222 ERROR 18060 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             :
>   [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template
>   "products": Could not parse as expression: "/@{'/edit/' +
>   ${product.id}}" (template: "products" - line 32, col 24)
>
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse
>   as expression: "/@{'/edit/' + ${product.id}}" (template: "products" -
>   line 32, col 24)

here is the html/thymeleaf code:

```
    <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
        <td th:text="${product.id}">Product ID</td>
        <td th:text="${product.name}">Name</td>
        <td th:text="${product.brand}">Brand</td>
        <td th:text="${product.madein}">Made in</td>
        <td th:text="${product.price}">Price</td>
        <td>
            <a th:href="/@{'/edit/' + ${product.id}}">Edit</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a th:href="/@{'/delete/' + ${product.id}}">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Here is the applicable Spring Boot Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
public ModelAndView showEditProductPage(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("edit_product");
    Product product = productService.get(id);
    mav.addObject("product", product);

    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping("/delete/{id}")
public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
    productService.delete(id);
    return "redirect:/";       
}
```

If I comment out the last td section, the rest of it works fine.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The syntax for Thymeleaf URLs is quite specific - and different from the example in the question. See [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#link-urls) for some examples.

Comment: Your example: `th:href="@{/edit/{id}(id=${product.id})}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use following:

```
<tr th:each="product : ${products}">
    <td th:text="${product.id}">Product ID</td>
    <td th:text="${product.name}">Name</td>
    <td th:text="${product.brand}">Brand</td>
    <td th:text="${product.madein}">Made in</td>
    <td th:text="${product.price}">Price</td>
    <td>
        <a th:href="@{/edit/{id}(id=${product.id})}">Edit</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id=${product.id})}">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

See the syntax [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

Comment: This doesn't follow the Thymeleaf syntax. I don't think it will work. I think it will treat `${product.id}` as a literal. This works: `th:href="@{/edit/{id}(id=${product.id})}"`. Are things different under the Spring dialect, perhaps?

Comment: So does that mean things are _not_ different under the Spring dialect? (I don't use Spring, or its Thymeleaf dialect).

Comment: Yes, that worked @Monzurul.  Thank you!  The tutorial where I got it from had it wrong.  https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-boot-crud-example-with-spring-mvc-spring-data-jpa-thymeleaf-hibernate-mysql#Create.  Actually, I haven't tested what you have now.  I tested what you had before and it worked:            <a th:href="@{/edit/${product.id}}">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a th:href="@{/delete/${product.id}}">Delete</a>

Comment: @MonzurulHaqueShimul - perhaps you can update your answer to help us understand the two approaches: standard dialect vs. Spring dialect? It seems the Spring dialect has some additional flexibility not in the standard dialect. I would be very interested in having a better understanding of that, if possible - many thanks!

Comment: OMG.. I had the same error. It seems the codejava tutorial should be fixed.

Comment: Just remove the forward slash / in the `<h3><a th:href="/@{/users}">List of Users</a></h3>` so it will be like this `<h3><a th:href="@{/users}">List of Users</a></h3>`